# How to capture terminal output to text file from my python script

Tags: python

I want to capture terminal message and save it to a text file while my python script is running.. I want to capture error messages as well.

-Don't want to execute this using batch file.
-help me where should i put those command on my script

```
import base64

import sendgrid

import os

import pandas as pd

import time

from datetime import date, timedelta


from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Email, Content, Mail, Attachment

    # Python 3
    import urllib.request as urllib

except ImportError:

    # Python 2
    import urllib2 as urllib


list = pd.read_csv('emaildb.csv')

email = list['Email']

merchant = list['Merchant']

today = date.today()

yest = today - timedelta(1)

yest1 = yest.strftime('%Y%m%d')

yest2 = yest.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

now1 = time.strftime("%B %d %Y  %H:%M:%S") 

sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey='sample API')



i = 0

while i < len(list):

    file_name1 = "REPORT_"+yest1+"_"+str(merchant[i])+".pdf"

    file_name2 = "REPORT_"+yest1+"_"+str(merchant[i])+".xls"

    S1="REPORT "+str(merchant[i])+" "+str(yest1)

    B1 = "Test"

    with open(file_name1,'rb') as f:
        data1 = f.read()
    encoded1 = base64.b64encode(data1).decode()



    with open(file_name2,'rb') as f:
        data2 = f.read()
    encoded2 = base64.b64encode(data2).decode()

    mail = {
        "attachments": [
        {
          "content": encoded1, 

          "filename": file_name1,
        },
        {
          "content": encoded2,
          "filename": file_name2,
        }
      ],      
      "personalizations": [
        {

          "to": [{
              "email": email[i]
          }],
          "subject": S1
        }
      ],
      "from": {
        "email": "test.com"
      },
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "text/html",
          "value": B1
        }
      ]
    }

    response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail)
    print("["+now1+"] "+email[i]+" "+file_name1)
    if response.status_code == 202:
        print('Success')
    else: print('Failed')
    print("\n")
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: `$ python script_name.py > logs.txt 2> errors.txt`

Comment: what if i want to include date and time on the text file?

Comment: Do you want to redirect some statement from within your python file? Or just redirect whatever gets printed out from the script to a file @Cel

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh i want to print to .txt file whatever the output message in the terminal, btw im calling the python script via .bat and scheduled it to run via windows task scheduler.

Comment: i want it to look like a logs.

Comment: Then use a logger module where you direct whatever you want from within the file!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh how?

Comment: take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh i dont know where and how to start this in my script. maybe you can help me with this?

Comment: Can you start by looking at the duplicate questions marked above @Cel

Comment: i already checked those duplicate answers a while ago before i created this question, but unfortunately i couldn't find one.